# redirecting page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I am fairly new to PHP MVC framework, codeigniter and in the process of developing my first website using the MVC framework. I am having trouble with my site navigation page as I want to create links that will redirect the user to the another page of the site.

Here is my controller (home_controller.php)

```
class Home_controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('index');
    }

    public function login(){
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

This is what i have in views file where i am attempting to set a link to the login page.

```
    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?> home_controller/login/">Staff</a>
```

After running the application and attempting to navigate sign in/staff link, an error is displaying
The requested URL / home_controller/login/ was not found on this server.

I have already loaded the url helpers from autoload.php file
i have set the base_url from the config.php file to http://localhost:8888/

But its still not working for me.

Comment: chnage `home_controller` to `Home_controller`

Comment: I have changed it to Home_controller and still dont work

Comment: Did you bother to read the documentation or do the tutorial within the documentation?  It's very easy to follow and all of these basics are fully covered.

Comment: yes i have followed the documentation

Comment: Carefully follow this section step-by-step:  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<li>
  <a href="oneoffpayment.php">Sign in ￬</a>
  <ul class="hidden">
    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/home_controller/login/">Staff</a></li>

  </ul>
</li>
```

and in `config.php` file `base_url` function should be empty

> **Make sure If you are using CI3+ then file name should be `Home_controller.php`. If you using  3.0- then file name should be `home_controller.php`**

Comment: I tried removing the base_url function from config.php but it does not work at all now

Comment: did you add `index.php/` in URL??

Comment: the same error, The requested URL index.php/home_controller/login/ was not found on this server.

Comment: how your file name?? can you remove controller word in file name and inside controller. it works

Comment: sorry i changed the filename to controller and also to class Home in the file. I have changed the base url to home/login and same error

Comment: No do like this. File name - **Home.php** inside method. **home** in base url same its empty